# Replacing a specific line in a text file with a variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
 def appendingfile():
        OpenFiles1 = open("modules.txt", "a")
        NewModule = (FreshModule.get())
        ModuleToAppend = (ModuleInput.get())
        for line in OpenFiles1:
            if ModuleToAppend in OpenFiles1:
                OpenFiles1.write(NewModule)
```

I'm unsure of how to replace a specific line in a python file with one of my variables. But before I even get to see the results I'm getting this error saying unsupportedOperationL not readable and I'm confused of how to approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to replace or append?

Comment: You can use a temporary file to save the result and then rename the temporary file to overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read from a file opened in "a" mode. use "r+" instead.
This is the code I tested

```
def appendingfile():
    with open("modules.txt", "r+") as OpenFiles1:
        NewModule = "NewModule"
        ModuleToAppend = "ModuleToAppend"
        content = OpenFiles1.read()
        if ModuleToAppend in content:
            OpenFiles1.write(NewModule)
```

Comment: Okay I can read and write in the file now, I've tried figuring out how to replace a specific line in the file but I'm having no success or rather I just don't know the syntax as everywhere I searched, the results have not been fruitful.

Comment: Can you provide samples of before and exepect after for you modules.text ?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation of this function, there are several modes in which you can open a file in python:

'r' for reading
'w' for writing (overwrites existing files)
'a' for appending (only writes at the end, this is the problem in your script)
'+' for updating (reading and writing)

When you open with writing or updating mode, there is this sort of pointer (the seek position) telling python where to write on. If you open in the appending mode, this pointer is always on the end of the text, regardless of the seek position.

Try opening in 'r+' mode for reading and updating.